# Weird cross browser issue with float:right

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with `float:left` and `float:right`. I have never seen such issue before. I must oversee something.

I tried giving the wrapper a fixed width, I tried giving the search box a fixed width. Nothing worked. If you zoom out in Chrome, it will also bug. What is the issue for this?

CSS in question:

```
.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-width: 980px;
  width: 90%;
}

.logo {
   float: left;

   margin-top: 27px;
}

.search {
  float: right;

  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.35);
  padding: 9px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="logo"><img ../></div>
   <div class="search">[...]</div>
   <br style="clear:both;" />
</div>
```

Issue: Why is the search box not floated to the right side of the wrapper in all browsers / zooming?

Edit:

**Issue solved!** Thank you SO, and "rblarsen" and "Anonymous.X"!

Comment: Your image is not "selfexplained". Explain what the actual issue is and add the code please (CSS and html).

Comment: The code you posted is not how Chrome renders it. Check the dev tool and you'll see an extra `<div style="float:right;">` between `logo` and `search`. That's not how you apply `float`. remove that for starter.

Comment: Btw you didn't even tell us which browsers you're referring to. We had to guess. Guessing is not part of a good question.

Comment: @U r s u s: Thats why I provided a screenshot, you can see I am using "Chrome" and "Firefox" and which browser is showing it correctly, or am I wrong?

Comment: @hresult even if it might be obvious which browser it is, it is still guessing. As of that you still should include those informations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you give your `.wrapper {overflow:hidden;}` it fixes the problem.

I believe that it is because the `.wrapper` is not having any height, and therefore doesn't align in the center as it should. By adding `overflow:hidden;` you make the div the same height as your content, as long as you don't specify a height for the `.wrapper`.

**EDIT:**

`overflow:hidden;` can cause future problems. Check the comment by t.niese, to avoid these.

Comment: Fixing such a problem with `overflow: hidden` is not the best solution, as it does not fix the actual reason and it might lead to other problems later, e.g. if the OP would like to have a submenu. The actual problem is the `#user_navigation`  which on the one hand is invalid because a `div` is not a valid descendant of `ul`, but more important this element has a height of `46px` and `float: right` while the _container_ just has a height of `43px` as of that the `#user_navigation` _blocks_ the search file.

Answer (score 1):

try this
1. add `position:relative` to your wrapper

```
.wrapper {
          margin: 0 auto;
          min-width: 980px;
          width: 90%;
          position:relative;
         }
```

2. add `position:absolute;right:0;` to your floated div like this

   `<div style="float:right;position:absolute;right:0"></div>`